# Selecting the next sibling, only if this span is showing

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I need to give a certain span a specific color, but only when it's previous sibling has "display: block". I don't have direct access to the HTML so this are the only classes I can work with.

```
<div class="price-content">
  <span class="old-price">
  **<span class="new-price>**
  <span class="percentage">
</div>
```

I have this all over the page repeating, "old-price" is hidden by default. But sometimes it has "display: block". How can I give "new-price" a specific color, only when "old-price" is displaying?

Comment: I think you need to use small JavaScript for this. I can't think of CSS solution. Can you show something that you've tried so far?

Comment: It is possible to do in css if the `display: block` is an inline style, otherwise - yes, requires javascript (and arguably that's a less flimsy option in any case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery, look for all the `.old-price` elements. If they've got display:block, then modify their sibling `.new-price` element. Here's an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.each($('.price-content > .old-price'), function(i, el) {
    $oldPrice = $(el);
    
    if ($oldPrice.css('display') === 'block') {
      $oldPrice.next('.new-price').css('color', 'purple');
      // Or maybe do 'addClass' for semantic's sake
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price-content">
  <span class="old-price" style="display: none">$5.98</span>
  <span class="new-price">$5.15</span>
  <span class="percentage">14%</span>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="price-content">
  <span class="old-price" style="display: block">$5.98</span>
  <span class="new-price">$5.15</span>
  <span class="percentage">14%</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Something simpler worked for me, just adding the if statement, but I'll select it as the right answer as it would have worked too.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you need JavaScript to do this. A simple solution would be to add a new class that represents whether the `.old-price` element is `display: block` (called `block` below).

```css
.old-price.block + .new-price {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="price-content">
  <span class="old-price block">OLD PRICE</span>
  <span class="new-price">NEW PRICE</span>
  <span class="percentage">%</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the original post to mention that i don't have direct access to the HTML.

Comment: Right, but you have access to JavaScript which can modify HTML elements.